# In mySQL workbench how can I rename table / column in a way that updates the whole model?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm unable to rename tables or columns in mySQL workbench v 8.0 (on Win10).

I have a simple database model in mySQL workbench. It has 2 tables, each with a primary-key (PK). There is a 1:1 relationship between the tables so that the PK from table 2 is listed as a foreign-key (FK) in table1. 
By just letting mySQL workbench do its thing I get:

[image: screenshot of tables in mySQL workbench]

The problem is that when I change the default table and column names in table2 the rest of the model is not updated. For example changing:

- table2 -> meaningfulName
- idtable2 -> id

[image: edit table and column names]

gives me this:

[image: actual result]

but I am expecting:

[image: expected result]

This seems like it should be trivial, is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no refactoring feature in MySQL Workbench which would take care of such name changes. You have to do this manually.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but confirms the conclusion I already reached, thank you for taking the time.